# Altera equivalent of the Xilinx Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC

Tags: fpga, xilinx, intel-fpga, soc

I'm new the the FPGA world. I was wondering if anybody could tell me the Altera equivalent of the Xilinx Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC?

I'm looking to buy a development board but it needs to be from Altera.

Thanks
Tom

Comment: Not sure this question is really on-topic here.

Comment: Terasic seems to be the biggest 3rd party source of Altera (now intel) dev boards, the stratix 10 line was only just recently released for sale so dev boards may be hard to come by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altera don't seem to have a nice easy to find selection table, but [Stratix 10](https://www.altera.com/products/fpga/stratix-series/stratix-10/overview.html) seems to be their current high-end part with an ARM-v8 core. Hard to know if its a good fit for your application without any more detail in your question. They don't appear to have their own development board (but maybe I missed something).